# Something do not understand about Analytic function when reading Complex analysis by Ahlfors

Tags: complex-analysis, harmonic-functions

I have some question when reading Complex analysis by Ahlfors.

---

1. Why analytic functions are true functions of a complex variable as opposed to functions which are more adequately described as complex functions of two real variable? I understand that the $\frac{\partial{f}}{\partial{\bar{z}}}=0$, but I still can not understand this sentence.
   [image]
2. The following seems to give a method to compute the conjugate harmonic function of $u(x,y)$. I don't know what means $\bar{f}(z)$, is it be made by conjugate the coefficient? And I do not know Why " $f(z)$ is only determined up to a purely imaginary constant."
   [image]
   I am really confused with this page, could you get me some reference(I have searched in Google but can not get a proper one) or answer my confusion? Thank you very much!

Comment: Clearly holomorphic functions are an example of functions of the form $f(x,y)$, but form a special class in that they are the ones which do not depend on both $z$ and $\bar z$ and are thus functions of a 'single' complex variable (the variable being $z$).

Comment: For your second question, note $\overline{f(z)} = \overline{\sum a_k z^k} = \sum \overline{a_k} (\bar z)^k = \bar f (\bar z)$

Comment: Note $f$ is only determined up to an imaginary constant in the sense that we only care that the real part of $f$ is $u$, so the imaginary part can be anything which makes $f$ analytic (and adding a constant, including an imaginary one, does not change analyticity)

Comment: Thank you very much!@BrevanEllefsen